# Passing parameters in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I'm working on a blackberry application which requires to pass a parameter to another screen so that some data is diplayed but i'm not able to achieve this. cna anyone help me.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any code, it is difficult to provide you code. But here is the basic strategy:

- Extend the Screen class.
- Add your own constructor, which will also call the super constructor.
- In your own constructor, provide an additional parameter.
- In the class you want to call the Screen class from, call the overloaded constructor.